# Mule Filter Processor based on Creation timestamps

Tags: mule

The documentation [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Anypoint+Filter+Processor) states the below

This option allows you to define an expiration time for the message.

> To define an expiration time based upon the time a message entered the
> flow, enter a Mule Expression to call a variable that provides this
> date and time in ISO 8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ), and an
> expiration time in milliseconds. (Earlier in the flow, you will need
> to name and define this variable so that it extracts the date and time
> information from your message's metadata.) The expiration time will be
> calculated based on the timestamp extracted from the message, and the
> filter will discard messages received after that expiration time.
>
> To define an exact date and time after which messages should expire,
> enter a date and time in ISO 8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ), and
> an expiration time in milliseconds. The expiration time is calculated
> from the precise date and time you enter, and the filter will discard
> messages received after that expiration time.

I can't understand how this filter works ?, What kind of usecase would warrant this filter ?,

My take on the use of the filter is as below, And I think its wrong but for what its worth I am putting it down here ...

The filter is used to kill messages that take more than "X" milliseconds to be processed by the flow

To use it do the below

The message created date should be stored in a variable right when the message enters the flow and then use the filter somewhere down the flow, the filter will reference variable (created earlier) and a "expires in" value to check if the current time is less than (variable created earlier + expires in) .. If true let the message proceed else remove the message.

Comment: I think you understand it correctly, not sure what troubles you about it... It sounds legit to want to drop messages if you know, for ex., that your SLA mandate you have to process it in less than X millisecs or not after a timestamp.

Comment: Alright thanks ... Its just that the name of the component did not explicitly state the functionality :)